# How to connect to multiple shards using Scala Jedis in Elasticache Redis?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, jedis

I get a successful connection using `JedisPool` when it comes to 1 shard (in cluster-mode); however, when it comes to more than 1 shard in Elasticache Redis, it errors with not being able to cache. I have read that `JedisCluster` is required. Am I correct on this?

My code is built with the values like so:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.{Jedis, JedisPool, JedisPoolConfig}

object RedisPool {
  private val redisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig
  redisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(LocalConfig.Redis.maxConnections)
  redisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(LocalConfig.Redis.maxIdleConnections)
  private val redisPool: JedisPool = new JedisPool(
    redisPoolConfig,
    LocalConfig.Redis.host,
    LocalConfig.Redis.port,
    LocalConfig.Redis.ttlSeconds,
    LocalConfig.Redis.user,
    LocalConfig.Redis.password,
    LocalConfig.Redis.ssl)

  def getRedisConnection: Jedis = {
    redisPool.getResource
  }
}
```

I have tried using the same parameters in `JedisCluster` but to no avail, this is not working for me and I really don't know where to start in Scala. I would appreciate any help.